# Why do I need to restart OS after some package upgrade?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, apt, package-management

On Ubuntu, when running `sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade`, why sometimes it asks me to restart my OS and sometimes not?

What do the packages that have that restart requirement have in common? Is it not possible to update such a package without restart OS requirement?

If I am correct, `sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade` can also update/upgrade kernel. Does kernel update/upgrade also require OS restart?

Thanks.

I often keep my Ubuntu up indefinitely long, because I am always running some programs and I don't want to interrupt them.

Comment: Ask ubuntu developers. Restarting the upgraded program is enough, or all programs which depends on an upgraded library.

Comment: It depends on what's being updated. When the kernel itself, kernel modules, or  libraries are updated, it's best to reboot to make sure that applications and processes aren't broken by trying to reference older versions.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what is running and being updated. The kernel needs to be restarted no matter what. If a main component gets updated such as glibc you may need to restart every application. If that is the case a reboot is the  easiest. Run the update and type `lsof | grep deleted`. You will see if the kernel is holding any of those files opened still.

Answer (score 2):

A reboot is rarely mandatory, even if notifications say so, but it is easier than restarting all the dependent services and applications. Examine the updated packages with `apt-cache show [package name]` or `apt changelog [package name]`, to decide if there are critical security updates, or if you can get by without them until reboot.

Since you mentioned having important programs running that you do not want to interrupt, I heard it is possible to [livepatch](https://linux-audit.com/livepatch-linux-kernel-updates-without-rebooting/) kernel updates without rebooting, but the setup adds additional complexity and support, so distros don't automatically include it.